# class and map, hashMap immutable cl?

Tags: java

How could I immute this class ?, I think I'm doing fine but the getExits () I can't put it as final.

How would you do it so that the whole class is immutable?

[link problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoSXH.jpg)

```java
final public class Location {
    private final int locationID;
    private final String description;
    private final Map<String, Integer> exits;

    public Location(int locationID, String description, Map<String, Integer> exits) {
        this.locationID = locationID;
        this.description = description;
        if(exits != null) {
            this.exits = new HashMap<String, Integer>(exits);
        } else {
            this.exits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        }
        this.exits.put("Q", 0);

        this.exits = Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.exits);  <---------

    }
    
    public int getLocationID() {
        return locationID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Integer> getExits() {
        return exits;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You could use an immutable map for `exits`.

Comment: Add `this.exits = Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.exits);` at the end of the constructor.

Comment: I added it and I get an error, attach a link in the publication with the image of the problem

Comment: Remove `final`. Or assign the new map to a local variable first, add the extra mapping, *then* assign the local variable to the `final` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `exits` is `final`, you need to complete the building of the map before assigning to the field, so use a local variable for that.

The copy-constructor simply turns around and calls `putAll`, so the code will be simplified by doing the same.

```java
public Location(int locationID, String description, Map<String, Integer> exits) {
    this.locationID = locationID;
    this.description = description;

    Map<String, Integer> tempExits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    if (exits != null)
        tempExits.putAll(exits);
    tempExits.put("Q", 0);
    this.exits = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempExits);
}
```

Comment: @AZCHILENO Don't know the challenge you're trying to solve, so don't know how it could have issue with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is immutable as it is.  Since you don't define any methods that modify the contents of the class, it is immutable.  If you want to insure that no method can be added in the future that will modify the data in your class, you can create `this.exits` as an immutable Map in your constructor.  The other two instance variables in your class are already immutable.

One way to do this would be to wrap your Map object so that it is immutable.  You'd do this at the end of your constructor, after your Map is fully formed.  You'll need to use a local variable initially so that `exits` can stay `final`.  Here's how to do that:

```
public Location(int locationID, String description, Map<String, Integer> exits) {
    this.locationID = locationID;
    this.description = description;
    Map<String, Integer> exitsTmp;
    if(exits != null) {
        exitsTmp = new HashMap<String, Integer>(exits);
    } else {
        exitsTmp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
    exitsTmp.put("Q", 0);

    this.exits = Collections.unmodifiableMap(exitsTmp);
}
```

Comment: I added it as I edited it in the problem description, but I get an error, it points to this.exits and an arrow pointing to that place. Is this how I put it back in the description of this post?

Comment: Ooos.  I forgot about `final`.  Yes, as @Andreas says, you either need to remove `final` from the definition of `exits`, or assign the map to a local variable at first, and then assign to `this.exits` just once at the end of your constructor.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry.  You caught the first 30 seconds of my edit.  I realized that I had left a stray `this.` in there that shouldn't be there.  @Andreas made a nice improvement anyway.  He's got you covered.  The idea of both answers is the same, of course.  Whatever got you to a solution is fine by me :)